# Frame rate drop with larger number of sprites in libdgx

Tags: libgdx

I'm making game that uses tiled map, and on it have 20 characters walking around.
FPS is over 50 with 12 characters.
When the total character is over 15, FPS is under 30.So it makes my game too slow.
Do you have any experience using Spriter or any other method to increase  FPS with 20 characters! I mean spriter is https://brashmonkey.com/

[image: this is my map]

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you are drawing your characters? 15 characters should not give the performance dip you're seeing, so there is likely something wrong with how you are rendering them.

Comment: here my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/iydnxrf6y815ov3/NhanVatMiniGame.java?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

In my game I'm drawing directly textures instead and frame rate is high as expected. Are you doing all your drawing between    `batch.begin()` and     `batch.end()` ?

Check out this tutorial and how drawing loop should look like:

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/02/LibGDX-Tutorial-3-Basic-graphics.aspx